# Can i add Google plus Sign In as a module in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-signin, android-studio-2.1

**Please don't tag as duplicate without reading it fully.**

I am aware of things related to integration of Google sign in in android,and i had done it before in one of my project, I am using latest Google repository in android SDK and Studio version 2.1.2

As per this picture

[image]

**We can include Google Cloud APIs directly as a module of any project**, my question is **can we do the same thing for Sign in through Google API ?**

Hope so there exist a way doing it, If anyone can guide it or has any references please answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, there is sample module provided by Google on GitHub here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/easygoogle

It also has instructions on how to use it and it's also very simple and optimized.

You can try it as it's opensource.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: okay got it , But if i am using firebase then is it ok to do this ?

Comment: offcource it is ok.